# Ansible /SSH questions?

Tags: permissions, ssh

I am trying to understand something between SSH and ansible set on inventory. I am running a playbook deployment and whenever I set the inventory like that :

```
[status]
qastatus ansible_ssh_user=ansible ansible_ssh_host=172.16.19.34 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/credentials/ansible_id_rsa 
I am having permission denied but when I set like that 

[status]
172.16.19.34 ansible_connection=local
```

it start running the deployment process find and stop here:

```
TASK: [nodejs_app | Pull down code] ******************************************* 
failed: [172.16.19.34] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["s3cmd", "-c", "/root/.s3cfg", "get", "s3://snapav-code/cs-system-status/cs-system-status-7ab76c7ec22af26fa3605d55750b6050e5ca17d5-2015-11-02_03-23-46--75.tar.gz", "/var/cs-apps/cs-system-status/7ab76c7ec22af26fa3605d55750b6050e5ca17d5-2015-11-02_03-23-46--75"], "delta": "0:00:00.148056", "end": "2015-11-02 22:45:36.958560", "item": "", "rc": 1, "start": "2015-11-02 22:45:36.810504"}
stderr: ERROR: /root/.s3cfg: Permission denied
ERROR: Configuration file not available.
ERROR: Consider using --configure parameter to create one.
```

I don't know why ??? what should I do to fix it ?

Comment: Are you using `become_user=sudo` or `become=true` in your site.yml file
If you are not using kindly add them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can ssh to the remote host with the correct user name without using ansible cmd

```
ssh uname@host
```

once you've done it, edit your `/etc/ansible/hosts` file
for example this is how I connect to my vagrant box with ssh

```
# Ex 1: Ungrouped hosts, specify before any group headers.
[all:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant


#green.example.com
#blue.example.com
#192.168.100.1
#192.168.100.10
[slave]
{{some_ip_here}}
...
```

Now just run the command you want or quickly test with:

```
ansible slave -m ping
```